# Resizing height or width as percentage minus value with jQuery and maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: jquery, height, width, aspect-ratio

I want an image to be 100% the width of the window *minus* the height of a header and its margin. *At the same time*, it should be no wider than the width of the window. This, I think I have achieved with the following code:

HTML:

```
<header></header>

<img id="photo" src="http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4031/4718599034_5ab720d0f9_b.jpg" realwidth="1024" realheight="768" />
```

CSS:

```
header {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:#000;
    margin:20px;
}

img {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    left:0px;
    max-width:1024px;
    max-height:768px;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-left:20px;

}
```

And, jQuery:

```
function setSize () {
   var windowHeight = $(window).height();
   var headerHeight = $('header').height();
   var windowWidth = $(window).width();


   $('img').height(windowHeight - headerHeight - 40);

   $('img').width(windowWidth - 40);
}


   $(window).resize(function () {
setSize();
setRatio();
   });

setSize();
```

[Here's the JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/EYpbU/)

What I can't do and what I want to do is maintain the aspect ratio of the image. How might this be done?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the image's NATIVE height attribute, instead of its CSS height, the width will automatically follow the aspect ratio.

```
$('img').attr('height',(windowHeight - headerHeight - 40)+'px');
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. And whilst that works for one dimension, it doesn't seem to apply to both equally. That is, width will follow height, but height won't follow width as well...